# TypeScript historyMethod type

Tags: typescript

After reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/History) of the history method, I'm not sure how to implement this using TypeScript. The error I'm getting is that a `string` type cannot be used to index `History`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'History'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'History'.

This was working before I converted my original JS to TS. How would you remedy this?

```
/**
 * Handles the query parameters.
 * @param {String} key The key in the URL.
 * @param {String} value The value in the URL.
 * @param {Object} options The options of the key-value pair.
 */
const handleParam = ( 
  key: string, value: string | null | undefined, options: object = {} 
) => {
  // Server-side rendering does not have a window object. Don't query on SSR.
  if ( typeof window !== `undefined` ) {
    // historyMethod: push or replace
    // (https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/History)
    const { historyMethod = `replace`, nullDeletes = true } = options as any
    const params = new URLSearchParams( location.search )

    if ( value === undefined ) value = params.get( key )
    else if ( value === null && nullDeletes ) params.delete( key )
    else params.set( key, value as any )

    let target = window.location.pathname + `?` + params.toString()
    target = target.replace( /\/?\?$/, `` ) // remove empty search string

    history[historyMethod + `State`]( { path: value }, ``, target ) // <- Error here
    return value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have already used `as any` in your code, why not use it here too?

```
/**
 * Handles the query parameters.
 * @param {String} key The key in the URL.
 * @param {String} value The value in the URL.
 * @param {Object} options The options of the key-value pair.
 */
const handleParam = ( 
  key: string, value: string | null | undefined, options: object = {} 
) => {
  // Server-side rendering does not have a window object. Don't query on SSR.
  if ( typeof window !== `undefined` ) {
    // historyMethod: push or replace
    // (https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/History)
    const { historyMethod = `replace`, nullDeletes = true } = options as any
    const params = new URLSearchParams( location.search )

    if ( value === undefined ) value = params.get( key )
    else if ( value === null && nullDeletes ) params.delete( key )
    else params.set( key, value as any )

    let target = window.location.pathname + `?` + params.toString()
    target = target.replace( /\/?\?$/, `` ) // remove empty search string

    (history as any)[historyMethod + `State`]( { path: value }, ``, target ) // <- Error here
    return value
  }
}
```